# Outlook web add-in section is changed and I am unable to get from where add new add-ins for single user directly

Tags: outlook, manifest, outlook-web-app

Earlier there was an option "get-ins" where we were able to remove or add custom add-ins manually for single but in recent outlook web it is changed and now I am unable to update my custom add-ins manually for my local setup which I have to update very frequently for my testing

I tried adding through admin section but it comes under app and it uses the old data of add-in